# TicTacToe print winner

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game with two players. I am pretty far and it works for the most part. I can't figure out how to print out string stored in an array. I have seen lots of loops as examples. Please let me know whats goin on.

enter code here

```
    int main()
   {    time_t t;
char player1 [23];
char  player2 [23];
int Let;
int Turns = 0;

printf("\n Welcome to Galactic Tic Tac Toe:\n");
    printf("\n Please enter player 1's name");
    fgets(player1, 22, stdin);
    printf("\nPlayer 2's name?\n");
    fgets(player2, 22, stdin);

void winner (char board [][9], char player1 [][23], char player2 [][23]){
if (board [0][0] && board [0][1] && board [0][2] == 'X'){printf("\nPlayer 1 has won\n Congratulations : %s ", player1);}
if (board [0][3] && board [0][4] && board [0][5] == 'X'){printf("\nPlayer 1 has won\n Congratulations : %s ", player1);}
if (board [0][6] && board [0][7] && board [0][8] == 'X'){printf("\nPlayer 1 has won\n Congratulations : %s ", player1);}
if (board [0][0] && board [0][1] && board [0][2] == 'O'){printf("\nPlayer 2 has won\n Congratulations : %s ", player2);}
if (board [0][3] && board [0][4] && board [0][5] == 'O'){printf("\nPlayer 2 has won\n Congratulations : %s ", player2);}
if (board [0][6] && board [0][7] && board [0][8] == 'O'){printf("\nPlayer 2 has won\n Congratulations : %s ", player2);}
if (board [0][0] && board [0][5] && board [0][8] == 'X'){printf("\nPlayer 1 has won\n Congratulations : %s ", player1);}    
if (board [0][2] && board [0][5] && board [0][7] == 'X'){printf("\nPlayer 1 has won\n Congratulations : %s ", player1);}
if (board [0][0] && board [0][5] && board [0][8] == 'O'){printf("\nPlayer 1 has won\n Congratulations : %s ", player2);}
if (board [0][2] && board [0][5] && board [0][7] == 'O'){printf("\nPlayer 1 has won\n Congratulations : %s ", player2);}

}
```

Comment: I can add beginning code as well to help. I honestly have always not really understood printing loops and why they are typically used for arrays.

Comment: Yea sorry like i said completely new, I just posted it i think i messed up the initialization... maybe

Answer (score 3):

Your biggest problem:

```
if (board [0][0] && board [0][1] && board [0][2] == 'X')
```

This *does not* do what you think it does. You probably assume that this checks to see if all three of those spaces are marked with `'X'`. That is incorrect.

`&&` is a boolean AND operator, which means the left- and right-side operators are evaluated (independently) as *booleans*.  So what you've written means:

```
if (                     // if
   board[0][0]           // board[0][0] is non-zero 
   &&                    // and
   board[0][1]           // board[0][1] is non-zero
   &&                    // and
   board[0][2] == 'X'    // board[0][2] is equal to 'X'
)
```

You haven't shown how you initialize your board (presumably with a space `' '`), but whatever (printable) character you store there will evaluated as a boolean TRUE.

So this expression *should* be:

```
if ((board[0][0] == 'X') && (board[0][1] == 'X') && (board[0][2] == 'X'))
```

---

On to the next problem:

> I honestly have always not really understood printing loops and why they are typically used for arrays.

Well there's no such thing as a *printing loop*. There are just *loops*. You can call `printf` in a loop if you want to.

To understand why we need loops, consider a different version of Tic-Tac-Toe where the board is 100 x 100. What would your "did someone win?" logic look like then?

It should be easy to see that coding `if( board[0][0] .... board[99][99]` and all possible combinations would quickly become exhausting for a human to code.  Computers on the other hand enjoy doing the same (or similar) tasks repetitively. It's up to the human (you) to ensure that energy is spent on something useful.

Comment: yeah, this definitely needs to be fixed!  +1

Comment: that would be insane, thanks for the help. here is the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem at the printf because player1 and player2 are char** but printf expects char*.

Comment: How would i change that?